# Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : <text>:1:15: unexpected symbol 1: ID ~ 0+Offset Length

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I would like to ask you for help. I am trying to perform MICE imputation of missing values in my dataset. Here is part of the code:

```
imputed_Data <- mice(data, m=5, maxit = 10, method = "PMM", seed = 200)
```

Unfortunately, this code returns the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:15: unexpected symbol
1: ID ~ 0+Offset Length
                  ^
```

Does anybody knows where the mistake is? "ID" and "Offset Length" are variables in my dataset.

Thank you,

Blanka

Comment: Can’t have spaces in column names

Comment: Thank you Hugh, I have deleted all the spaces from column names, but it didn't help. The error is still the same.

Comment: UPDATE: I resolved this issue by myself. The problem is in the illegal characters in the title in resource dataset. It is necessary to remove all + , % 1 2.